# Format mysql query log file output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logfile

I created a querylog.log file and place the line below:

**log="C:\Users\paul\Documents\dumps\querylog.log"**

in my.ini under [mysqld] to log all mysql queries on my computer but the problem that I have is that the queries are not properly formatted in the file. Is it possible to have the output logs formatted where everything will be written on a separate line (like have all the queries on one line)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: End each line with `\n` (has to be in double quoted string).

Comment: I can't, the data are inserted in the file automatically

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could achieve this is, using **triggers**.

As soon as any log is written to the log file, fire a php script which

1. Opens the logfile
2. Appends the file and adds a new line
3. Closes the connection with the file (so that it's usable again by the log writer).